# How does the author apply the implicit function theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $m$ and $k$ be integers with $0\leq m\leq k$. Let $M\subset \mathbb R^k$ and $p\in M$.
>   Suppose there is an open set $U\subset \mathbb R^k$ and a smooth map $f:U\to \mathbb R^{k-m}$ such that $p\in U$, the differential $df(q):\mathbb R^k\to \mathbb R^{k-m}$ is surjective for every $q\in U\bigcap M$, and $$U\bigcap M=f^{-1}(0)=\{q\in U\mid f(q)=0\}.$$ Then show that: There is an $M$ open neighbohood $U_0\subset M$ of $p$, an open set $\Omega_0\subset\mathbb R^m$, and a diffeomorphism $\phi_0 U_0\to\Omega_0$.
>
> proof:Define $$X:=\ker df(p)\subset\mathbb R^k.$$ We choose a $k-m$ dimensional linear subspace  $Y\subset\mathbb R^k$ such that $\mathbb R^k=X\bigoplus Y.$ Then the restriction of $df(p)$ to $Y$ is a vector space isomorphism from $Y$ to $\mathbb R^{k-m}$. Hence **by the implicit funtion theorem**, there are open neighborhoods $V\subset X$ and $W\subset Y$ of the origin and a smooth map $g:V\to W$ such that $$Q:=\{p+x+y\mid x\in V,y\in W\}\subset U, g(0)=0,$$ and, for all $x\in V$ and $y\in W$, we have $$f(p+x+y)=0\iff y=g(x).$$ Hence assertion (i) holds with $$U_0:=Q\bigcap M=\{p+x+g(x)\mid x\in V\}, \Omega_0:=V\subset X\cong\mathbb R^m,$$ and the diffeomorphism $\phi_0:U_0\to\Omega_0$ given by $\phi_0(p=x=y):=x$ with inverse $\phi_0^{-1}(x):=p+x+g(x).$ This proves the theorem.

Here is the implicit function theorem:

> Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^k\times\mathbb R^l$ be open and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R^l$ be a smooth map. Let $(x_0,y_0)\in\Omega$ such that $$f(x_0,y_0)=0,\det (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0))\neq 0.$$ (Here $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb R^{l\times l}$ denotes the Jacobi matrix of the map $y\to f(x_0,y)$ at the point $y=y_0.$) Then there are open sets $V\subset \mathbb R^k$ and $W\subset\mathbb R^l$ and a smooth map $g:V\to W$ such that $(x_0,y_0)\in V\times W\subset\Omega,g(x_0)=y_0,$ and $$f(x,y)=0\iff y=g(x).$$ for all $(x,y)\in V\times W.$

I'm so confused, how does the author apply the implicit function theorem for this case? It seems that he actually defines a new function $h:(x,y)\to f(x+y+p), R^k\times R^k\to \mathbb R^{k-m}$, and apply the theorem on it. But this function has its domain as $R^k\times R^k$, not as $R^{m}\times R^{k-m}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(p) = 0$ and ${\partial f(p) \over \partial x}$ is surjective.
Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{k-m}$. By reordering the indices if
necessary, we may assume that ${\partial f(p) \over \partial x_1}$ is invertible.

The implicit function theorem gives a smooth function 
$\xi_1:V_2 \to W_1 $, with open sets $V_2,W_1$ such that
$p_2 \in V_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^m, p_1 \in W_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^{k-m}$
such that
for all
$x_1 \in W_1, x_2 \in V_2$
we have $f((x_1,x_2)) = 0$ **iff** $x_1=\xi_1(x_2)$.

Note that $\Omega_0 = M \cap (W_1 \times V_2) = \{ (x_1,x_2) | x_2 \in V_2, x_1 = \xi(x_2)\}$. Hence $\Omega_0$ is $M$-open.

Now consider the map $\eta:V_2 \to \mathbb{R}^k$ given by $\eta(x_2) = (\xi_1(x_2),x_2)$, and note that $\eta(V_2) = \Omega_0$

We see that if $(x_1,x_2) \in \Omega_0$, then $\eta^{-1}((x_1,x_2)) = x_2$,
letting $U_0=V_2$ and $\phi = \eta^{-1}$ finishes the proof.

Comment: Why is $\partial f(p) \over \partial x$ surjective?

Comment: Wasn't than one of the assumptions? $df(p)$ surjective?

Comment: Are $df(p)$ and $\frac{\partial f(p)}{\partial x}$ the same

Comment: How do you define $df(p)$?

Comment: directional derivate

Comment: By the way, why does the fact that the restriction of $df(p)$ to $Y$ is an isomorphism imply that the theorem applies? Thanks.

Comment: Its a more complicated way of doing what I did.

Comment: Could you read the end of my post and answer these questions that I have? I'd really appreciate it if you do, I have been dealing with them for a long time.

Comment: The difference is that I am using explicit coordinates whereas the proof above uses subspaces of corresponding dimensions. In the expression $f(p+x+y)$, the point $p \in \mathbb{R}^k$ satisfies $f(p)= 0$, and we have $x \in X, y \in Y$. We have $\dim X = \dim \ker {\partial f(p) \over \partial x} = m$ and $\dim Y = k-m$. The $h$ you have above is a map $h : X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}^{k-m}$.